# Illegal character In email address after removing whitespaces

Tags: java, android, regex, email

I am taking in an email address via EditText. I got an error saying the address contained whitespaces, no problem. I implemented address.removeAll("\\s" , ""); and now am getting the error

- 04-16 09:37:43.009: W/System.err(1632): javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal character in local name in string ``606#7f080011app:id/enterEmail}''

Here is my code for capturing the email and converting to a String.

```
      EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);

      String to = e.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

On the line where I use the address and get the error:

```
msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
```

I have done some research trying to find if it is a parsing issue or what would be causing it but found nothing. Anybody know why I would be getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of e?

Comment: In this instance it is just a simple yahoo email address: user123@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're converting your `EditText` to a `String` instead of getting its text and doing the `replaceAll()` on it.

Simply replace this:

```
String to = e.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

With this:

```
String to = e.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Comment: Then simply use: `e.getText().toString().replaceAll(...)`

Comment: Thank you. Give me a few minutes and I will accept the answer.